# Recuperar lista nome de lista de contatos em um edit android

Tags: android, android-activity, app, android-intent

Td bem pessoal ?
Estou com um problema no desenvolvimento de um app, pois quando chamo a tela de cadastro dele antes quero pegar o nome e o telefone do contato selecionado e enviar para o edit da activity, porém eu não consigo recuperar o nome e nem os dois ao mesmo tempo, apenas o numero, por favor poderiam me ajudar a recuperar os dois ao mesmo tempo? segue o código que utilizo para recuperar o numero e que está funcionando atualmente:

```
public void SelecionarContato(){
        Intent contatos = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK); //CHAMANDO UMA ACTIVITY COM A CONSTANTE DE ESCOLHER UM DADO A SER RETORNADO
        contatos.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); //SELECIONANDO O CONTEUDO UTILIZANDO A CONTACTS PROVIDER

        //VALIDANDO
        if (contatos.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            //CHAMO OS CONTATOS 
            startActivityForResult(contatos, REQUEST_SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER);

        }
    }

//TRATANDO O RESULTADO DO RETORNO DOS CONTATOS
    protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent Data){
        if (RequestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER && ResultCode == RESULT_OK){ //O ULTIMO PARAMETRO É PARA CASO O USUARIO CANCELE
            //Pegar a URI e a Query do contactProvider e o numero do telefone
            Uri contatoUri = Data.getData();
            String[] projecao = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contatoUri, projecao, null, null, null);

            //SE O CURSOR RETORNAR UM VALOR VALIDO ENTÃO PEGA O NUMERO
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
                int indexNumero = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                String number   = cursor.getString(indexNumero);

                //ação do que recebe o numero do contato e envia para a activity
                telefone.setText(number);
                telefone.setEnabled(false);

            }
```

Comment: Seria melhor postar o que você tentou fazer, pois em teoria não existe razão nenhuma para não conseguir obter os 2 dados ao mesmo tempo, visto que é um ContentProvider que retorna um Cursor.

Comment: No seu array projecao, você passou o número e o contato?

Comment: Tentei de diversas maneiras mas já estou sem ideias de como fazer, a ultima tentativa foi essa, tentar recuperar ele dentro do array projeção junto com o nome, lembrando que o código que mandei acima funciona perfeitamente para trazer o o numero:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coluna do `ContactsContract` que você deve usar para recuperar o nome é essa:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
```

Depois você pode tentar fazer como já estava codificado antes:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent Data){
    if (RequestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_CONTACT && ResultCode == RESULT_OK){ //O ULTIMO PARAMETRO É PARA CASO O USUARIO CANCELE
        //Pegar a URI e a Query do contactProvider e o numero do telefone
        Uri contatoUri = Data.getData();
        final String[] projecao = new String[]{
           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, 
           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
        };

        final int INDEX_NUMBER = 0;
        final int INDEX_NAME = 1;

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contatoUri, projecao, null, null, null);

        //SE O CURSOR RETORNAR UM VALOR VALIDO ENTÃO PEGA O NUMERO
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            String number   = cursor.getString(INDEX_NUMBER);
            String name = cursor.getString(INDEX_NAME);

            //ação do que recebe o numero do contato e envia para a activity
            telefone.setText(number);
            telefone.setEnabled(false);
            nome.setText(name);
            cursor.close();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Poxa mano, era só isso!!! Deu certo caraaaaaa !!! muito Obrigado Marcião !!!